# How can I fix network connectivity check issue over VPN?

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, windows-10-universal, internet-connection

I'm using a piece of `C#` code where I check if my `PC` having internet access or not **over the VPN**.

```
var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
if (profile != null)
{
        // returning True/False
        var IsInternetAvailabele= profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() >= NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess;
        // .......
        // .......
        //.. Some Other Code..
}
```

It was working fine on my `Windows 10` with version `1803`. After I received updates from `Microsoft`, my `Windows 10` version updated from `v1803` to `v1809`.

On previous version of `Windows 10 v1803`:

```
var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
var value = profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel(); // returning "Internet Access"
```

But after upgradation of `Windows 10 v1809`:

```
var profile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
var value = profile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel(); // returning "Local Access" (No Internet Access)
```

**But my internet browsing is working fine on `browsers`.** I tried to restart my pc, reset my `network adapter`, update my windows 10. But all in vain.

Is it some kind of `winodws sdk` bug in new version or something else!

**Note: This issue only occurs over VPN. And on older versions of Windows 10, this issue is not existing.**

Comment: When are you getting the connectivity level? The doc suggests getting it with the [NetworkStatusChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.networkstatuschanged) event. Are you using that? It might be that at the time of retrieving it has not established the connection yet.

Comment: Yes, its the same method that I'm using right now.

Comment: Does it never return a different connectivity level upon a following event? Does a follow-up event ever happen?

Comment: Also not that according to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.networkinformation.getinternetconnectionprofile#Windows_Networking_Connectivity_NetworkInformation_GetInternetConnectionProfile) `GetInternetConnectionProfile` returns the "The preferred profile represents the connection that is the most likely to be used when sending and receiving traffic to and from the internet", which might not be the correct profile.

Comment: You are right @Neijwiert. I also tried this by setting network priority from Network adapter.

Comment: My PC also connect over VPN, but the code worked well on my side. My OS build version is 1809. Could you please check if there're some changes on your VPN? If possible, please try another VPN to see if you still face the same issue. And what kind of VPN were you using?

Comment: I'm using VPN of one of my clients. Its connected via **Pulse Secure**.

Comment: I think, its a bug of `windows 10`. Its not working on my office laptop while working fine on my other laptop with same `Windows 10 version`.

Comment: We are seeing this issue when VPN through a mobile hotspot too!

Comment: Its really a buggy thing.